# Parse tagged value with (VB)Script

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a tagged value type: script.
I paste a string like:

```
ET-Powersupply OFF
prTimeBefore = '1'  :(01,real,   'Time before [ms]'                 ,'0..100000');//Time before measurement
psDvcName = 'ETPS'     :(02,string, 'Device name [str1;str2;...]'      ,'');         //
psSndCmd  = 'ET1_STBY_OFF ; ET1_OUT_OFF'     :(04,string, 'Send CmdStr/@cmd [str1;str2;..]'  ,'');         //CommandString in device-specific Lib or '@direct cmd'
prSndRec  = '1'     :(05,real,   'snd/rec/both [1/2/3]'             ,'1..3');
```

is it possible to get automatically this output in the tagged value **value**:

```
prTimeBefore = '1'; psDvcName = 'ETPS'; psDvcName = 'ETPS'; prSndRec  = '1'
```

I know that i should search after **'** and **=** and the word before **=** and the value inside the **' '**

but how can i automatically let the tagged value be parsed? Picture to example above:
[image: example]

thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to paste the whole first text into the tag value when creating / editing it, then have EA automatically strip it so that the value ends up as in text 2?

Comment: yes, that procedure could solve my problem. Yes automatically

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of going about this; you can write an in-EA script or you can build an Add-In. The latter is the more complete solution, but requires more work.

With the scripting method, you would create a context-sensitive script to set the tag and use that script instead of the regular EA GUI. This method is not foolproof, as you would still be able to bypass the script and set the tag value incorrectly using EA's regular GUI.

With an Add-In, you can make EA react so that whenever someone sets the tag you correct it if necessary. Add-Ins can react to events, while scripts must be called by the user.

Scripts are stored inside the EA project, or in an MDG Technology which all users need to configure. Add-Ins need to be distributed and installed on each client machine.

To create a script, proceed as follows:

1. Select View - Scripting in the top menu.
2. In the Scripting window, click the left-most icon to create a Project Browser group and/or a Diagram group. Scripts in these groups are available to users by right-clicking in the project browser / diagram.
3. In either group, create a new script in whichever language you prefer (VBScript, JScript or JavaScript).
4. Make sure the script responds to the right type of object (probably Element), then write the script to open an input dialog, parse the input value and set the tag to the parsed value.
5. If you work in the target project, the script is available to all users immediately.

If you write an Add-In, you'll want it to respond to the EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified event. Check that the item/object is of the right type (again, most likely Element), then go through its tags and check if there is a "Script" tag whose value is of the raw variety, then parse it and set it to the parsed value.

The API is documented in the help file under Automation. The Object Model contains the interfaces available both in scripts and Add-Ins, while the Add-In Model contains the events an Add-In can respond to.